# Android Notification Manager issues

Tags: android, android-notifications

My app get crash after receiving the notification it shows in Log Cat that NosuchMethodError for the line No 107 i.e. .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).build(); in my file, can someone help,
My device version is 4.0+ and code is as follows

```
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    final Object systemService = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Retrieve notification details from the intent
    final String tickerText = bundle.getString(TICKER_TEXT);
    final String message = bundle.getString(MESSAGE);
    final String notificationTitle = bundle.getString(TITLE);
    final String notificationSubText = bundle.getString(SUBTITLE);
    int notificationId = 0;
    Intent pintent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, pintent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                                .setContentText(message)
                                .setTicker(tickerText)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/raw/horn"))
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();

    NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) systemService;
    notificationMgr.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because [setWhen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setWhen%28long%29) was added only in API level 11. Check if you are running the project in any lower version devices.

If that's the case, then you have to go for backward compatibility and try to learn about it.